# Web2Py Syntax Error Non-Keyword Arg After Keyword Arg

Tags: python, web2py

I'm trying to implement this code on my localhost:

```
def form_a():
   form = SQLFORM(db.registration, deletable=True, request.args(0), upload=URL(r=request, f='download'))
   if form.accepts(request.vars, session):
       if not form.record:
           response.flash = "Your input data has been submitted."
       else:
           if form.vars.delete_this_record:
               session.flash = "User record successfully deleted."
           else:
               session.flash = "User record successfully updated."
           redirect(URL(r=request, f='form_a’))
   records = db().select(db.registration.ALL)
   return dict(form=form, records=records)
```

But I get a ***non-keyword arg after keyword arg*** error at this line:

```
   form = SQLFORM(db.registration, deletable=True, request.args(0), upload=URL(r=request, f='download'))
```

And a ***EOL while scanning literal error*** at this line:

```
redirect(URL(r=request, f='form_a’))
```

I'm using Python 3 and Web2Py 2.4.6, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All positional arguments must come before keyword arguments, so here `request.args(0)` is causing the error as `deletable=True` a keyword argument was passed before it.

> form = SQLFORM(db.registration, deletable=True, request.args(0),
>   upload=URL(r=request, f='download'))

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

> In a function call, keyword arguments must follow positional
>   arguments. All the keyword arguments passed must match one of the
>   arguments accepted by the function and their order is not important.

And in   `redirect(URL(r=request, f='form_a’))` you're using different types of opening and closing quotes.

It must be either `f='form_a'` or `f="form_a"`

Answer (score 2):

You have a non-keyword argument:

```
form = SQLFORM(db.registration, deletable=True, request.args(0), upload=URL(r=request, f='download'))
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

After a keyword argument:

```
form = SQLFORM(db.registration, deletable=True, request.args(0), upload=URL(r=request, f='download'))
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You either have to make `deletable` a non-keyword argument or make `request.args(0)` a keyword argument.

As for the second error, this quote right here isn't actually a closing quote:

```
redirect(URL(r=request, f='form_a’))
                                 ^
```

Notice how it's curly. Replace it with a regular single quote.

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
form = SQLFORM(db.registration, deletable=True, request.args(0), upload=URL(r=request, f='download')),
```

You have `deletable=True, request.args(0)` which is a non-keyword argument after a keyword argument. Which is not valid syntax..

And In `redirect(URL(r=request, f='form_a’))`

```
redirect(URL(r=request, f='form_a’))
                                 ^ This is not what you want..
redirect(URL(r=request, f='form_a'))
                                 ^ This IS what you want..
```